# Custom routing in Azure functions using HttpTrigger attribute

Tags: c#, function, azure

I have a compiled Azure function and I want to define a custom route using the HttpTrigger attribute.

My code looks like this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "qotd/{format}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string format, TraceWriter log)
{
  var quote = GetRandomQuote();
  if (format == "json")
  {
     return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, quote, "application/json");
  }
  else
  {
     var strQuote = quote.Text + Environment.NewLine + quote.Author;
     return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, strQuote, "text/plain");
  }
}
```

When I call it like this:
**localhost:7071/api/qotd/json**
I get 404.

When I call it like this:
**localhost:7071/api/qotd/?format=json**
then the function succeeds.

If I call it like this:
**localhost:7071/api/qotd/**
I get a rather nasty error:

> "Exception while executing function: QotDFunction -> Exception binding
>   parameter 'format' -> Binding data does not contain expected value
>   'format'..."

How can I define the binding in Route parameter of HttpTrigger, so that I can call my function like this:

**localhost:7071/api/qotd** - for a default value of parameter format

and

**localhost:7071/api/qotd/json** - to pass "json" as a value for format?

For Route I tried also "qotd/{format:alpha?}" but got the same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that I had to explicitly rebuild the project.  Rebuilding it forced VS to create a new function.json file with proper route.  Without doing so, function.json still kept the old, default route.

Answer (score 2):

I test your code and do not get the same errors as you.

I create a new azure function and its default Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions is version of 1.0.2. And I use version 1.0.7 of Azure.Functiuons.Cli to run the function. My target framework of project is .Net Framework 4.6.1.

I use your code like below:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "qotd/{format:alpha?}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string format, TraceWriter log)
        {

            if (format == "json")
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "aaa", "application/json");
            }
            else
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "aaa", "text/plain");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call function like `http://localhost:7071/api/qotd`, it passes "text" as a value for format.

[image]

When I call function like `http://localhost:7071/api/qotd/json`, it pass "json" as a value format.
[image]

Comment: "if" statement to select request method or header in single method is a monkey code. If MS doesn't allow to do normal api, then its design bug and technologies with design bug should not be used until fix.